# Wrap long string in Django template with no effect to rendered text (spaces, indentation, etc.)

Tags: html, django-templates, word-wrap

I have a line of code in a Django template that accomplishes exactly what I want (display information in a tooltip), but it is far too long. Here's the line:

```
<abbr title="Comment: {{ material.comment|default:'' }}{% if material.comment and material.location %}&#10;Location: {% endif %}{{ material.location|default:'' }}">
  {{ material.name }}
</abbr>
```

If I try wrapping `title`'s value to make it readable like this, it totally messes up the formatting in the rendered `<abbr>`:

```
<abbr title="Comment: {{ material.comment|default:'' }}
  {% if material.comment and material.location %}&#10;
  Location: {% endif %}{{ material.location|default:'' }}">
    {{ material.name }}
</abbr>
```

I tried searching for HTML tags that would allow me to wrap lines of code without reflecting these changes on rendered text, but no luck, so I'm turning to you. My guess is that the answer must be clear to experienced programmers, so I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your HTML tidy, you might consider moving this logic into the Django view that is preparing the material object for the template, or into a template tag or filter. That way, the complex logic for generating the tooltip text can be tested independently of the HTML template.

Example:

```
# in your models.py
class Material(models.Model):
    # existing fields here...

    def tooltip_text(self):
        tooltip_parts = []
        if self.comment:
            tooltip_parts.append(f"Comment: {self.comment}")
        if self.location:
            tooltip_parts.append(f"Location: {self.location}")
        return '&#10;'.join(tooltip_parts)
```

Comment: The HTML entity didn't work in the method, so I just changed it to `\n` and now it works well! I just have to call `{{ material.tooltip_text }}` and it works. Thanks for the help! The takeaway here for me is that the **logic heavy lifting must be done in the models, not in the templates**. I appreciate that.